# Rename folder without old folder

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Copy;
use File::Copy::Recursive;

$old_folder=$ARGV[0];
$new_folder=$ARGV[1];
$folder_loc=$ARGV[2];

print "Content-type:folder rename\n\n";

#rename($arg1,$arg2) || print "Don't have permission to rename.<br><br>";
File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy("$folder_loc/$old_folder","$folder_loc/$new_folder");

print "Renaming Done!";

exit;
```

here my old folder is also exist after the folder rename.how can i remove old folder after renaming. pls help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [`File::Copy::Recursive::dirmove`](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm#dirmove%28%29) instead of `dircopy`

Comment: thanks alot macroS, one more thing, my file size is approx 1.2gb so it's taking 25 min time to rename it is there any method to reduce the time.

Comment: @picnic4u: you're welcome! About your additional question: I assume that you have a **directory** whose size is about 1.2 Gb, and that it containis several files and sub-directories. In that case, the disk access time is what is limiting performance, and there's not much you can do about it. One alternative, assuming that your program runs on linux is to use the linux `mv` command, which you can invoke from perl using [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: @macroS: i m using windows system. so for me any suggestion

Comment: @picnic4u: I don't have a Windows machine here to test, but you can use `system()` from perl to invoke Windows/DOS commands such as `move` or `xcopy` + `delete`. Maybe you can try this on a test directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File::Path](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) to remove entire directory trees (Including files).